# Prometheus PromQL is not aggregating counts over a period of time correctly

Tags: go, prometheus, grafana, metrics

I'm collecting number of messages being consumed with Prometheus.
For each message that is consumed, I increment Counter once.
Now, the prometheus server config is that scraping them each 30s.

I use this PromQL query to have the number of messages consumed by each minute:
`sum(rate(consumer_count[1m]))`

I use `sum()` because I have 4 workers. What I get, is an incorrect number. Because in my tests, for each consumption, I also log a message, counting those logs give me nearly 20k messages per minute, while prometheus, shows nearly 1k messages per minute (except the first minute which it shows 20k).

I also am running this query in Grafana panel. If it helps.

Comment: `I use this PromQL query to have the number of messages consumed by each minute: sum(rate(consumer_count[1m]))` - that is not what this query is doing. From the [docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate): `rate(v range-vector) calculates the per-second average rate of increase of the time series in the range vector.`. `consumer_count[1m]` will give you a range vector of the counter's values over the past minute. The `rate` function will give you the average increase... per second.

Comment: If you want the increase of your counter over the past minute, use the [increase function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase): `sum(increase(consumer_count[1m]))`